# Unsuccessful changing 'Chapter' to 'Annex'

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I am trying to change the title 'Chapter' in appendices into 'Annex' but am unable to do so. I looked up and found the solution as
`\renewcommand\appendixname{Annex}`
but this does not solve my problem and the title still shows as 'Chapter'.

My guess is it might be because I have changed the titleformat of the chapters (or it might not be because of it....)

If someone could help me with the issue. My code in the preamble looks like:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\center}{Chapter \thechapter}{0.3em}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-15pt}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\fontsize{14}{10}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}

\begin{document}
All contents that matters.....

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Some Annex}
    \input{Chapters/Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] including a documentclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you hardcoded the word `Chapter` here:

```latex
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\center}{Chapter \thechapter}{0.3em}{\LARGE}
```

To use the right word, regardless of whether you're in the main content or in the appendices, use `\chaptertitlename` as [documented](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf) in the `titlesec` package documentation (page 4):

> `\chaptertitlename`
>
> It defaults to `\chaptername` except in appendices where it is `\appendixname`. Use it instead of `\chaptername` when defining a chapter.

Remember to add `{}` to make the trailing space significant:

```latex
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\center}{\chaptertitlename{} \thechapter}{0.3em}{\LARGE}
```